# applying keyed state on top of stream from co group stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam

- I have two kafka sources
- I am trying to perform world count  and merge the counts from two streams
- I have created window of 1 min for both  data streams and applying coGroupBykey , from DoFn , i am emitting `<Key,Value> (word,count)`
- On top of this `coGroupByKey`  function , I am applying stateful `ParDo`
- Let say if i get `(Test,2)` from `stream 1`, `(Test,3)` from `stream 2` in same window time then  in `CogroupByKey` function , i ll merge as `(Test,5)`, but if they are not falling in same window , i will emit `(Test,2)` and `(Test,3)`
- Now i will apply state for merging these elements
- So finally as result i should get `(Test,5)`, but i am not getting the expected result , All elements  form `stream 1` are going to one partition   and 
  elements from `stream 2` to another partition , thats why i am getting  result

```
(Test,2)
(Test,3)
```

```java
// word count stream from kafka topic 1
PCollection<KV<String,Long>> stream1 = ... 

// word count stream from kafka topic 2
PCollection<KV<String,Long>> stream2 = ... 

PCollection<KV<String,Long>> windowed1 = 
  stream1.apply(
    Window
      .<KV<String,Long>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.millis(60000)))
      .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)))
      .withAllowedLateness(Duration.millis(1000))
      .discardingFiredPanes());

PCollection<KV<String,Long>> windowed2 = 
  stream2.apply(
    Window
      .<KV<String,Long>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.millis(60000)))
      .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)))
      .withAllowedLateness(Duration.millis(1000))
      .discardingFiredPanes());

final TupleTag<Long> count1 = new TupleTag<Long>();
final TupleTag<Long> count2 = new TupleTag<Long>();

// Merge collection values into a CoGbkResult collection.
PCollection<KV<String, CoGbkResult>> joinedStream =
    KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(count1, windowed1).and(count2, windowed2)
      .apply(CoGroupByKey.<String>create());

// applying state operation after coGroupKey fun 

PCollection<KV<String,Long>> finalCountStream =
  joinedStream.apply(ParDo.of(
    new DoFn<KV<String, CoGbkResult>, KV<String,Long>>() {

      @StateId(stateId)
      private final StateSpec<MapState<String, Long>> mapState =
          StateSpecs.map();

      @ProcessElement
      public void processElement(
        ProcessContext processContext,
        @StateId(stateId) MapState<String, Long> state) {

          KV<String, CoGbkResult> element = processContext.element();
          Iterable<Long> count1 = element.getValue().getAll(web);
          Iterable<Long> count2 = element.getValue().getAll(assist);
          Long sumAmount = 
              StreamSupport
                .stream(
                    Iterables.concat(count1, count2).spliterator(), false)
                .collect(Collectors.summingLong(n -> n));

          System.out.println(element.getKey()+"::"+sumAmount);
          //  processContext.output(element.getKey()+"::"+sumAmount);

          Long currCount = 
            state.get(element.getKey()).read() == null
              ? 0L
              : state.get(element.getKey()).read();
          Long newCount = currCount+sumAmount;
          state.put(element.getKey(),newCount);
          processContext.output(KV.of(element.getKey(),newCount));
        }
      }));

finalCountStream
    .apply("finalState", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String,Long>, String>() {

      @StateId(myState)
      private final StateSpec<MapState<String, Long>> mapState =
        StateSpecs.map();

      @ProcessElement
      public void processElement(
        ProcessContext c,
        @StateId(myState) MapState<String, Long> state) {

          KV<String,Long> e = c.element();
          Long currCount = state.get(e.getKey()).read()==null
            ? 0L
            : state.get(e.getKey()).read();
          Long newCount = currCount+e.getValue();
          state.put(e.getKey(),newCount);
          c.output(e.getKey()+":"+newCount);
        }

      }))
    .apply(KafkaIO.<Void, String>write()
                  .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                  .withTopic("test")
                  .withValueSerializer(StringSerializer.class)
                  .values());
```

Comment: I am using  Flink runner

Comment: How to collect all  counts of a given word in single part ion partition ( on same flink operator instance ) so that we can get (Test,5) <-- excepted result

Comment: correction for the above  CoGroupKey fun code  snippet
PCollection<KV<String, CoGbkResult>> joinedStream =
            


KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(count1, windowed1)
                    .and(count2, windowed2)
                    .apply(CoGroupByKey.<String>create());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use a Flatten + Combine approach, which should be give you simpler code:

```
   PCollection<KV<String, Long>> pc1 = ...;
   PCollection<KV<String, Long>> pc2 = ...;
   PCollectionList<KV<String, Long>> pcs = PCollectionList.of(pc1).and(pc2);
   PCollection<KV<String, Long>> merged = pcs.apply(Flatten.<KV<String, Long>>pCollections());
   merged.apply(windiw...).apply(Combine.perKey(Sum.ofLongs()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    options.as(FlinkPipelineOptions.class)
            .setRunner(FlinkRunner.class);

    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);


    PCollection<KV<String,Long>> stream1 = new KafkaWordCount("localhost:9092","test1")
            .build(p);

    PCollection<KV<String,Long>> stream2 = new KafkaWordCount("localhost:9092","test2")
            .build(p);


    PCollectionList<KV<String, Long>> pcs = PCollectionList.of(stream1).and(stream2);
    PCollection<KV<String, Long>> merged = pcs.apply(Flatten.<KV<String, Long>>pCollections());

    merged.apply("finalState", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String,Long>, String>() {

        @StateId(myState)
        private final StateSpec<MapState<String, Long>> mapState = StateSpecs.map();

        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c, @StateId(myState) MapState<String, Long> state){

            KV<String,Long> e = c.element();
            System.out.println("Thread ID :"+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
            Long currCount = state.get(e.getKey()).read()==null? 0L:state.get(e.getKey()).read();
            Long newCount = currCount+e.getValue();
            state.put(e.getKey(),newCount);
            c.output(e.getKey()+":"+newCount);
        }

    })).apply(KafkaIO.<Void, String>write()
            .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
            .withTopic("test")
            .withValueSerializer(StringSerializer.class)
            .values()
    );

    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have set up both streams with the trigger `Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1))` and `discardingFiredPanes()`. This will cause the `CoGroupByKey` to output as soon as possible after each input element and then reset its state each time. So it is normal behavior that it basically passes each input straight through.

Let me explain more: `CoGroupByKey` is executed like this:

- All elements from `stream1` and `stream2` are tagged as you specified. So every `(key, value1)` from `stream1` effectively becomes `(key, (count1, value1))`. And every `(key, value2)` from `stream2` becomes `(key, (count2, value2))
- These tagged collects are flattened together. So now there is one collection with elements like `(key, (count1, value1))` and `(key, (count2, value2))`.
- The combined collection goes through a normal `GroupByKey`. This is where triggers happen. So with the default trigger, you get `(key, [(count1, value1), (count2, value2), ...])` with all the values for a key getting grouped. But with your trigger, you will often get separate `(key, [(count1, value1)])` and `(key, [(count2, value2)])` because each grouping fires right away.
- The output of the `GroupByKey` is wrapped in just an API that is `CoGbkResult`. In many runners this is just a filtered view of the grouped iterable.

Of course, triggers are nondeterministic and runners are also allowed to have different implementations of `CoGroupByKey`. But the behavior you are seeing is expected. You probably don't want to use trigger like that or discarding mode, or else you need to do more grouping downstream.

Generally, doing a join with CoGBK is going to require some work downstream, until Beam supports retractions.